# Typescript generics array with inheritance

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Im trying to create an array in typescript to contain different functions that accept different types but they all inherit from a base class.
like so:

```
interface A {
    name: string;
}

interface B extends A{
    bb: string;
}

interface C extends A{
    cc: string;
}

const funcs = [
    (param: B) => {

    },
    (param: C) => {

    },
]
```

and then use it like so

```
funcs[0]({name: "ASda", bb: "b_value"}) // error 'cc' is missing in type '{ name: string; bb: string; }'
funcs[1]({name: "ASda", cc: "c_value"}) // error 'bb' is missing in type '{ name: string; cc: string; }'
```

[TS playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+SOAWwgC5kBnMKUAcwG4sBfLLUSWRFAIWQgA9IIACbk02PMgBGkspWoh6TFm2jwkyAMK8BEYaNTi8CBLKq0GzLAgD2ISshgBXEAlEBeZAG0ceABQAHOCgiMi4ASmQ3AD5MFglGABofXACgkM0I6Njk5ESsAF0WJxdyTwAGfN8MAmIyACJUAGUhODqEqRlkOskAfQA3OAAbRwg6xgiAegneKChrKCxi13LK6qJSLqaWtuRjeoR+oZGxyenoOYWgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specified any type for your array of function `funcs`. With dynamic typing, your array signature is defined like so : `const funcs: (((param: B) => void) | ((param: C) => void))[]`

In that case, compiler doesn't know the signature of the function you actually use. According the above signature, you have to provide data covering all possible case : type `B` **and** `C` resulting in the error you see.

You could make it work by defining the type of your array of functions like so

```
const funcs: Function[] = [
    (param: B) => {

    },
    (param: C) => {

    },
]

funcs[0]({name: "ASda", bb: "b_value"}) //No error
funcs[1]({name: "ASda", cc: "c_value"}) //No error
```